# How to get user activity from Yammer API?

Tags: metrics, yammer

I'm trying to generate metrics for # threads, replies, likes and shares, I'm aware that Yammer API does not provide hard numbers for this out of the box, so what endpoint(s) could I look into, so I can do some data crunching to generate this metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the data export API to download the network data incrementally, then perform any actions on the CSVs on your machine.

Ref: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api